# Sending generated code elsewhere to NetLogo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, netlogo

I'm trying to work on an environment that its main function is to adopt Visual Programming to create NetLogo code (similar to Google's Blockly).

Right now, I'm using Unity3D to do the job and wondering if it's possible to access NetLogo from it. The objective is to send the generated code directly into the Code Tab, opening a blank project already with the code in the tab (without the user copying and pasting it there).

What I know up until now is that I can open NetLogo from Unity with a function called Process.Start, which takes 2 arguments: the first is the name of the target program to be executed ("NetLogo.exe"), the second one is a list of arguments that can be passed to the targeted program, which solely depends on each program, [as found here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1108055/execute-external-program.html) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx). However, I didn't understand much about these arguments, which is why I recurred to ask.

Do I need to also work on a Java/Scala environment to do this for me with the [Extensions API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API), or can I use these arguments in Process.Start to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't get an answer here, you might try https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/netlogo-devel

Comment: I see you've now also asked this at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netlogo-devel/jfSH5I5Tybs

Comment: cross-linking like this is polite, it prevents someone from wasting time helping you in one place with something you already got helped with elsewhere

Comment: Sure, I get it, I'd post the answer in both places whenever I got 'em. It's just because I thought that in the google groups it might be more complicated to get specifically suggestions regarding Unity3D, which wouldn't happen here. I'll be sure to update both sites if I manage to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a fully formed .nlogo file (it's basically a [text file with a specific format](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/File-(.nlogo)-and-Widget-Format)), and then launch NetLogo using your Process.start command with that filename as an argument so that NetLogo will open that specific file.

You could even create a .nlogo file as a template (with whatever interface items you want), and then use string search/replace to substitute in the code that you want in the code tab.

Alternatively, fancier things are possible with the [Controlling API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API) , but I don't know much about calling JVM code from within Unity, and I suspect that will be a bigger headache than you want... unless you really need a more tight-knit connection to NetLogo, or unless the performance overhead of starting a new NetLogo process each time is unacceptable.

Comment: The NetLogo file format is [currently undergoing a major redesign](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/pull/1547). The new format is not quite here yet, and the old format will likely still be supported for the foreseeable future, but it is something to keep in mind if you decide to go down that path.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm constructing a .nlogo file from Unity. What I did was create a sample project with just the setup and go buttons, get the "txt" file generated from the nlogo and appended right after the generated code in Unity. And @Nicolas Payette thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind.